# <w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, caching

Trying to run a project on my VPS but im constantly getting this error flagged up. i have tried clearing and installing everything fresh but the problem still occurs. any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
<t> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] restore cache container: 64.298367 ms
info  - Creating an optimized production build ...    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Pack got invalid because of write to: Compilation/modules|/home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[2].use!/home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/pages/_error.js
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Storing pack...
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Capturing build dependencies... (/home/admin/web/server/public_html/next.config.js, /home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/, /home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-swc-loader.js)
info  - Creating an optimized production build .<t> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] resolve build dependencies: 90.189044 ms
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Error snapshotting file timestamp hash combination of /home/admin: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/admin'
<t> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] snapshot build dependencies: 1.801434 ms
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
        at /home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:70754:13
        at jobError (/home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:47008:5)
        at /home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:47071:10
        at /home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:47968:13
        at /home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:131419:5
        at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:23493:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
        at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:23295:14)
        at AsyncQueue._handleResult (/home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:131389:21)
        at /home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:131372:11
        at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (/home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:47917:12)
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] No pack exists at /home/admin/web/server/public_html/.next/cache/webpack/edge-server-production.pack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/admin/web/server/public_html/.next/cache/webpack/edge-server-production/index.pack'
<t> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] restore cache container: 19.478739 ms
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] No pack exists at /home/admin/web/server/public_html/.next/cache/webpack/client-production.pack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/admin/web/server/public_html/.next/cache/webpack/client-production/index.pack'
<t> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] restore cache container: 9.156366 ms
info  - Creating an optimized production build ...    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Pack got invalid because of write to: Compilation/modules|/home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.js?absolutePagePath=next%2Fdist%2Fpages%2F_app&page=%2F_app!
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Storing pack...
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Capturing build dependencies... (/home/admin/web/server/public_html/next.config.js, /home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/, /home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.js, /home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-swc-loader.js)
info  - Creating an optimized production build .<t> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] resolve build dependencies: 102.05922 ms
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Error snapshotting file timestamp hash combination of /home/admin: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/admin'
<t> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] snapshot build dependencies: 2.324734 ms
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
        at /home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:70754:13
        at jobError (/home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:47008:5)
        at /home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:47071:10
        at /home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:47968:13
        at /home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:131419:5
        at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:23493:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
        at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:23295:14)
        at AsyncQueue._handleResult (/home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:131389:21)
        at /home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:131372:11
        at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (/home/admin/web/server/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:47917:12)```
````

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same error

Answer (score 46):

Resolved with deleting `.next` folder and running `yarn run dev` again.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [this discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35877), the suitable soulution in your case seems to be

```
cd [your project]
npm install -g n
sudo n stable
rm -rf node_modules/
rm -f package-lock.json
npm install
```

I really can't reproduce the error so I'm not 100% confident this is going to work but you can give it a try and let us know.°
I also think you can skip the installation of a stable node version so, if you already have one, just try the clean npm install.

Answer (score 0):

For me I just move my project to C:/ and return to work. But if you need to maintain the project in another disk, you can do this:

- Go to `your_project/node_modules/next/package.json`
- Change local in `_where` [(Local in package)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYsIU.png)
- Now you can start.

PS.: I don't know whats happening and a different form to change this package easily.
PS 2.: I google a lot, but didn't find anithing.

Answer (score 0):

On my part the issue occurred because there was no sufficient permission on the folder.

To fix it I ran :

```
sudo chmod 775 .
```

NOTE : [775 permission explained](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-775/)